# Secure data for MySql PHP

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I'm developing a PHP app and I would like to know how to secure my data in PHP for a MySQL query.

I use MySQLi. I use prepared queries to secure updates and inserts. But, for complexes queries, I generate the query dynamically.

So I would like know how to secure my data without prepared queries.

Comment: Then why not create a dynamic prepared statement?!

Comment: Don't do it...rethink your approach. Figure out a way to create a dynamic prepared query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others said, create a dynamic prepared query.

Hope [this](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli) will help you

Comment: Thanx for your help. But, in my server, mysqlnd isn't enabled which one is required for mysqli_stmt::get_result